# does spring data jpa do caching

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-data-jpa

I've got a simple repository that looks like this

```
public interface PlayerLevelRepository extends CrudRepository<PlayerLevel, Integer> {
    @Query("FROM PlayerLevel WHERE exp <= :exp ORDER BY exp DESC")
    List<PlayerLevel> findClosestToExperienceLevel(@Param("exp") long exp);
}
```

I was analyzing the response time from rests and saw that the first rest execution was ten times slower than the next.

So I decided to check the time of repository method (I don't have any other time consuming actions there) like this

```
@Override
public int findClosestLevel(long exp) {
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    int closestLevel = levelRepository.findClosestToExperienceLevel(exp).get(0).getLevel();

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    LOGGER.info("Execution time: {}", endTime - startTime);
    return closestLevel;
}
```

And I saw that the first invocation spends `35012440` aka `35 ms`. Second, third and other invocations spend ten times less time - `2194712` or `2ms`, `3058421` or `3ms` and so on.

My question is - does `Spring Data JPA` cache query results of something?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But your database does. Your JDBC driver also probably caches prepared statements. And maybe the first execution needs to open a connection to the database, too.

Comment: I would hope not. At least not automatically. What kind of database are u using? Because the database will have some sort of caching.

Greetings

Comment: I am using `postgresql`

Comment: It seems @JBNizet is right and it slower at first call because it opens the connection. I tested it with the additional separate repository method and it executes 10 times as fast too.

Comment: Opens the connection? You're not using a connection pool with already opened connections?

Comment: No, I am using it - at least `HikariCP` is used by default. But it sounds plausible in that case. It's slower on first call only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Data JPA is "just" a wrapper (or a nice facade) over JPA, so underneath you still have standard JPA capabilities. You have 1lvl cache on the `EntityManager` / `Session` level, and 2lvl cache on `EntityManagerFactory` / `SessionFactory` level. There are more types of cache, like: query result cache etc. You can read more about them [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html) (it's for older Hibernate version, but it should still be valid).

Comment: I see, so basically it does nothing else except giving convenient tools for repository methods?

Comment: Yes. It's "just" doing its magic :). Take a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/. There is not a single line about caching.